# asp.net validations

Tags: asp.net

I want to add a validation control to check if the first name and last name of a person entered consists of characters from A-Z and not any special characters and numbers? How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a good example of using a [regular expression validator for that](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998267.aspx). But don't forget O'Dell and Van Damme. :)

Answer (score 2):

use a regular expression validator and put the `[a-zA-Z]` as the reg ex to validate.
If you want support for hyphen and underscore then put `[a-zA-Z_\-]`

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator id="revalApha" runat="server" 
ControlToValidate="TextBox1" ValidationExpression="[a-zA-Z]+$" 
ErrorMessage="Only Alphabets allowed"> </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

I will advice against the custom validator since you need to write a function both in javascript and in c#

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Regular Expression validator or a Custom Validator.